# Can't disable hibernate logging

Tags: java, hibernate, logback

I am using logback for my custom logging purposes. I also integrated Hibernate to my application. Now I am trying to disable or set the level of Hibernate logging with no luck. I tried to to add the following properties in my hibernate.cfg.xml file but nothing changed.

```
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
```

Here is also my hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume students is the database name -->

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            SA
        </property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">

        </property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is also my logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>classname</key>
            <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${classname}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <append>false</append>
                <file>${classname}.log</file>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{20} | %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this ...

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="OFF"/>
```

... to your `logback.xml`

This will instruct Logback to ignore all log events emitted by Logger instances from the `org.hibernate` namespace.